# Data abort if CPU suspend in FIQ?

Tags: embedded, arm, interrupt

I'm developing the embedded system on ARM platform. And I just try to solve a random data abort issue on it. And as I try to focus the problematic lines on the register map for debugging, but another problem is the lines number are not always the fixed number.
Finally, I found that the waiting function call(just make the CPU to suspend for a specified time) will introduce the data abort problem.

I'd like to know what's the problem if we do a lot of things such as a complex computation in FIQ or IRQ? Would it introduce a data abort problem? Since the FIQ should disable all the other FIQ or IRQ during service routine, why would it introduce these kind of problem?

Ref

[What's the difference between FIQ and IRQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973933/what-is-the-difference-between-fiq-and-irq-interrupt-system)

[How to debug random data abort issue on arm based platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474700/how-to-debug-random-data-abort-issue-on-arm-based-platform)

Comment: have you verified all of your accesses are aligned?  you should be able to look at the stack (cortex-m) or link register (not cortex-m) and find the instruction that caused the abort.

Comment: Yes, I check the link register R14 but the address are not always point to the same address. And if I doing the same operation, it sometimes shut down sometimes slow not always a fix time. It's weird, but after I removing the waiting in FIQ it seems work!? Thank you for your reminder.